# Loading the output from TOleContainer.SaveAsDocument

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ole

I have an existing database with blobs contain OLE compound files. I have a requirement to read these OLE compound files and open them in the Delphi 7 TOleContainer control.

Note that I don't have the source of the app that reads and write to the database. The database remains in active use, so my solution will be used on an ongoing basis, not just for a one-off data extraction.

TOleContainer has a SaveAsDocument method, and by experimentation I have found that, for a given file, this method produces OLE compound files which are identical to those created in the database when that file is added.

However, TOleContainer does NOT have a corresponding LoadFromDocument method. It has other Load* and Create* methods, but none seem capable or suitable for loading the output from SaveAsDocument.

The delphi 7 implementation of SaveAsDocument is this, from the OleCtnrs.pas module:

```
procedure TOleContainer.SaveAsDocument(const FileName: string);
var
  TempStorage: IStorage;
  PersistStorage: IPersistStorage;
begin
  CheckObject;
  if FModSinceSave then SaveObject;
  FOleObject.QueryInterface(IPersistStorage, PersistStorage);
  if PersistStorage <> nil then
  begin
    OleCheck(StgCreateDocFile(PWideChar(WideString(Filename)), STGM_READWRITE
      or STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE or STGM_CREATE, 0, TempStorage));
    OleCheck(OleSave(PersistStorage, TempStorage, False));
    PersistStorage.SaveCompleted(nil);
  end;
end;
```

Please provide an implementation of LoadFromDocument which is capable of loading the output from SaveToDocument, and which I can use to patch OleCtnrs.pas. Or else point me to an existing solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the file by using `TOleContainer.CreateObjectFromFile`. Do not use `TOleContainer.LoadFromStream/File`, that only works with files that are saved with `TOleContainer.SaveToStream/File`. Files saved that way get a Delphi specific header containing a four byte code (`BDOC`) and size (and maybe something more).

Comment: I think you are right that TOleContainer.LoadFromStream/File, that only works with files that are saved with TOleContainer.SaveToStream/File.

However, while TOleContainer.CreateObjectFromFile accepts the output of TOleContainer.SaveAsDocument without throwing an exception, calling DoVerb(0)  or double-clicking on the control does NOT open the registered application; furthermore it is also dependent on the extension oof the filename passed in, which is not known.

Comment: To give a very simple example. Have a reference .bmp test file handy, then call the following code, where OleCOntainer is an instantiated TOleContainer. At the point where InsertObjectDialog pops up the dialog, click the Create From File radio button, browse to your .bmp file, and click OK:

    if (not OleContainer.InsertObjectDialog()) then exit;
    OleContainer.SaveAsDocument('c:\tmp\TestBMP.bin');
    OleContainer.DestroyObject();
    OleContainer.OldStreamFormat := true;
    OleContainer.CreateObjectFromFile('c:\tmp\TestBMP.bin', true);
    OleContainer.DoVerb(0);

Comment: The container will show a .bin icon (registered to VideoLAN on my system, and a spurious Explorer window is opened.

What I expected to happen is that container should show a .bmp icon , and Windows File and Fax Viewer should display the original bitmap.

From previous experiments, I suspect that CreateObjectFromFile is only suitable for loading native files with correct file extensions, NOT files embedded inside OLE compound files.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't know I couldn't use 4-space-indented code blocks in comments.

Comment: CreateObjectFromFile also give limited success with OLE compound files when _some_ versions of _some_ Office apps are installed. This is because those apps will open an OLE compound files containing an office file without complaining. Yet other versions of Office apps will open them if the file extension is correct.

For example, Word 2003 and Excel 2003 will open the compound doc regardless of its file extension; Word 2007/2010 will open the  compound doc _if_ its extension is correctly doc/docx; Excel 2007/10 will not open it all.

Comment: But by no means is CreateObjectFromFile a universal solution for opening the output of SaveAsDocument!

Comment: @colonel32: I never had problems with loading compound Office files with CreateObjectFromFile. I even succesfully opened Office XML files with CreateObjectFromFile that were saved with SaveAsDocument (they are not saved as zipfiles, but as compound documents with the zipfile in it - even extensions didn't matter, the compound document has a GUID/CLSID specifying the type). Since you mentioned a compound format I thought it would work with you too. PS: you did try it, didn't you? :)

Comment: Definitely! For a long time I *was* using CreateObjectFromFile. As I unit tested on more Office versions I had to code more workarounds, such as sniffing the compound file to guess what the extension would be so that 2007/2010 wouldn't balk at loading it with a .tmp extension. Then as I mentioned, Excel 2007/2010 refuses to open compound files completely. Then there are the OLE1.0 compound files that package up simple files like BMP, GIF, TXT, PNG which CreateObjectFromFile won't open at all. Then other OLE2.0 compound files like PDF and PSD, which CreateObjectFromFile won't open either.

Comment: It really does have to be a universal solution that will open *any* output from SaveAsDocument, regardless of the type and extension of the packaged file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for Delphi 2007 (should be the same for ), you can use 'TOleContainer.LoadFromStream'. From the Delphi 7 help file (emphasis mine):

> Call LoadFromStream to load an OLE object from a stream. If OldStreamFormat is true, LoadFromStream **loads OLE objects saved by a TOleContainer object** as well as OLE objects saved using the current format; if OldStreamFormat is false, LoadFromStream will not load OLE objects saved by the library. If there's already an OLE object in the container, it is destroyed and any changes the user made to it are discarded.

Comment: Thanks Ken, that's a useful comment that I had failed to spot. Leaving OldStreamFormat as the default of false, LoadFromStream does indeed throw an invalid Stre

Comment: However I'm pretty sure The_Fox below is correct: TOleContainer.LoadFromStream/File only works with files that are saved with TOleContainer.SaveToStream/File, albeit that the value of OldStreamFormat has to match in both the Save and Load calls.